# Missing permissions required by GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-permissions

Надо получить текущее местоположение устройства. При проверке разрешений выдаёт ошибку "Missing permissions required by GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION". Не пойму, что не так делаю?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Функция проверки разрешений:

```
private fun isLocationPermissionGranted(): Boolean {
    return if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), locationPermissionCode)
        false
    } else {
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        true
    }
}
```

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Студия на является правдой первой инстанции. Ее проверки могут и неверно срабатывать. Я бы больше верил линтеру из SDK и ошибкам исполнения.

Answer (score 0):

а разве координаты получают не через LocationManager?

типа

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minGPSTime,
        minGPSDistance, locationListener);

// слушатель географического положения
private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    // при изменении координат наблюдателя
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        showLocation(location);
    }

    // событие при отключении провайдера
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        checkEnabled();
    }

    // событие при включении провайдера
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        checkEnabled();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        showLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
    }

    // событие изменение статуса
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            mGpsProviderStatus = "Статус: " + String.valueOf(status);
        } else if (provider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            mNetProviderStatus = "Статус: " + String.valueOf(status);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Автор не говорил что ему нужно получить координаты. Ему нужно включить определение местоположения в библиотеке карт

Comment: значит, функция не видит разрешений, возможно, ошибка в определении package